Having An issue about calling Gemini API in Electron Js
I am having an issue with gemini API in electron js in this code I'm trying to make chatbot which remembers the previous messages unfortunately I'm getting an Error Message:

Uncaught Error: Check dependency list! Synchronous require cannot resolve module '@google/generative-ai'. This is the first mention of this module!

let history=[

]


const sendbtn=document.getElementById("send");

sendbtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  const messageDiv = document.createElement("div");
  messageDiv.classList.add("outgoing");
  messageDiv.innerText = prompttext.value;
  messagesContainer.appendChild(messageDiv);
  history.push({role: "user", content: prompttext.value})
  prompttext.value=""
  run()
})

const prompttext=document.getElementById("prompt");
const messagesContainer=document.getElementById("chat-main")

const { GoogleGenerativeAI } = require("@google/generative-ai");
const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI("myApıKey");

async function run() {
  // The Gemini 1.5 models are versatile and work with multi-turn conversations (like chat)
  const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-1.5-flash"});

  const chat = model.startChat({
    history,
    generationConfig: {
      maxOutputTokens: 100,
    },
  });

  const result = await chat.sendMessage(prompttext.textContent);
  const response = await result.response;
  const text = response.text();
  history.push({role: "model", content:text})
  const messageDiv = document.createElement("div");
  messageDiv.classList.add("incoming");
  messageDiv.innerText = text;
  messagesContainer.appendChild(messageDiv);
}

